# Parsing JSON File From iTunes API

Tags: ios, json, swift

The code below attempts parse through a json file that contains details about an artist and their music genre and was collected from the iTunes API. I am trying to  extract the  collectionName and artistName keys from the file with the use of the guard statement but it isn't working. It prints out parsing error.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            musicData()
        }
        let urlString = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Alex&media=music&entity=album"
        
        
        func musicData(){
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        
     guard let myData = data else {
        return
    }
    guard let rawJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myData, options: []),
        let json = rawJSON as? [String:Any] else {
            print("error serializing JSON")
            return
    }
            
    guard let musicDictionary = json["collectionName"] as? [String:String] else {
     print("Parsing error")
     return
}
   
}
        task.resume()

    }
let collectionName = musicDictionary["collectionName"]
let artistName = musicDictionary["artistName"]
}
```

Comment: How does the ‘ collectionName’ dictionary look like? Is it [String: String]? Or perhaps [String: Any]?

Answer (score 0):

The property you're trying to access is a level deeper. Better approach is to use `JSONDecoder`.

Model:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let resultCount: Int
    let results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let wrapperType: WrapperType
    let collectionType: CollectionType
    let artistId, collectionId: Int
    let amgArtistId: Int?
    let artistName, collectionName, collectionCensoredName: String
    let artistViewUrl: String?
    let collectionViewUrl, artworkUrl60, artworkUrl100: String
    let collectionPrice: Double?
    let collectionExplicitness: CollectionExplicitness
    let trackCount: Int
    let copyright: String
    let country: Country
    let currency: Currency
    let releaseDate, primaryGenreName: String
    let contentAdvisoryRating: String?
}

enum CollectionExplicitness: String, Codable {
    case explicit = "explicit"
    case notExplicit = "notExplicit"
}

enum CollectionType: String, Codable {
    case album = "Album"
}

enum Country: String, Codable {
    case usa = "USA"
}

enum Currency: String, Codable {
    case usd = "USD"
}

enum WrapperType: String, Codable {
    case collection = "collection"
}
```

Decoding:

```
guard let myData = data else {
    return
}
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: myData)
    print(response.results[0].collectionName)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: @MayowaPaul Don't forget to mark as right an upvote if the answer helped you out.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to tutorial that properly explains how to parse json from an API in swift? I am having a hard time learning.